# custom header was stripped off when forwarded from http to https

Tags: nginx, header

I have an nginx server forwarding all http traffice to https to the same backend server. I added a custom header on nginx for that directive. When I am testing it, I found the custom header is displayed in the http request, but it doesn't display in chrome developer tool for https traffic. Is there a way I can see this custom header in https traffice ?

thanks.

Comment: The links is tst-cms.avery.com. You can test it by useing http://tst-cms.avery.com.

Comment: Show nginx config